# Autolayout and iOS7, programatically added UIImageViews don't appear - seems Thread related

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uiimageview, constraints, autolayout

I have an array full of UIImages.  I load each image into a UIImageView and then add the UIImageView to a UIView, once done that UIView is added to a UIView which is on the display.

The problem is in iOS7 when I add the UIView with the UIImageViews to the other UIView they do not appear on the screen (all fine in iOS6).  If I then press the Home button and then go back into the app the images are there!

I know this sounds a little strange in that I could cut a UIView out of the process but there is a reason. There is also a reason why I do not store the UIImages in the Array as UIImageViews.

```
UIView *layerViewToAdd = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:presentationDisplay.frame];

for(UIImage tempImage in currentImages)
{
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:presentationDisplay.frame];
        [tempImageView setImage:tempImage];
        [layerViewToAdd addSubview:tempImageView];
}

[presentationDisplay addSubview:layerViewToAdd];
```

I have tried to force a screen redraw with [presentation setNeedsDisplay] and [presentationDisplay setNeedsLayout] but does not work.  I think the problem is to do with Autolayout/Constraints but not sure.

EDIT

Okay I have isolated the code, it seems to be thread related.  Looking at below code I call redrawLayersInBackground in the background which is the above FOR loop, then I call the presentLayersInView on the main thread which adds the the View that is already being displayed (the last row in the above more or less) - sorry I know I cut a lot of code out but it does much much more than just this (lesson learned).  This works fine in iOS6 but not iOS7, if I take out ALL the dispatch bits it works fine in both.

Is there a better way to build things up in the background and then add in foreground?

```
backgoundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("createlayers", 0);

dispatch_async(backgoundQueue, ^{

    UIView *layerViewToAdd = [self redrawLayersInBackground];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentLayersInView:layerViewToAdd];

    });

});
```

ANOTHER EDIT

This is the whole code;

It stores the layers of the view in an array and there is some comparing and testing to see if we already have the layer before downloading again.  The images that come down are large which is why I am going through so much trouble!

```
-(UIView *)redrawLayersInBackground
{
    int layerCount = 0;


    // This is the view which will contain all the new layers
    UIView *layerViewToAdd = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:presentationDisplay.frame];

    // Take a copy of all the layers then clear then, the copy will be used as a cache to build a new set of layers
    NSArray *tempLayerNames = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:layerNames];
    NSArray *tempLayerImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:layerImages];

    [layerNames removeAllObjects];
    [layerImages removeAllObjects];


    // This for is just to loop through all items, the dictionary is not used
    for (NSDictionary *enforceLoop in currentSetupInfo[@"layers"])
    {

        NSString *layerName =currentSetupInfo[@"layers"][[NSString stringWithFormat:@"layer%i", layerCount]];

        BOOL isFound = NO;
        UIImage *tempImage;
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:presentationDisplay.frame];

        int newLayerCount = 0;

        // Start a search for the layer in the list of old layers
        for (NSString *obj in tempLayerNames)
        {
            if([obj isEqualToString:layerName])
            {
                // NSLog(@"Found Layer : %@", layerName);

                [layerNames addObject:obj];
                tempImage = [tempLayerImages objectAtIndex:newLayerCount];
                [layerImages addObject:tempImage];

                isFound = YES;
                break;
            }
            newLayerCount++;
            // This layer is already visiable ont he screen, do not fade it in
            tempImageView.alpha = 1.0;
        }

        if (!isFound)
        {
            // NSLog(@"Downloading Layer : %@", layerName);

//            NSURL *layerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:layerName];

//            tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:layerURL]];

            tempImage = [self imageFromURLInString:layerName];

            [layerNames addObject:layerName];
            if(tempImage == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error - Image not fonud on server..........................................................");
                NSLog(@"Error - URL : %@", layerName);
                [layerImages addObject:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
            }
            else
            {
//                tempImageView.image = tempImage;
                [layerImages addObject:tempImage];
            }

            // Set this layer Alpha to zero, this way we can fade it in
            tempImageView.alpha = 1.0;
        }

        // NSLog(@"Image Layer : %i", layerCount);

        [tempImageView setImage:tempImage];

        [layerViewToAdd setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
        [layerViewToAdd addSubview:tempImageView];


        NSLog(@"Iterating");

        layerCount++;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSNumber *tempPercentage = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (float) (layerCount) / [currentSetupInfo[@"layers"] count]];

            [self updateSpinner:tempPercentage];
        });
    }

    return layerViewToAdd;
}


-(void)presentLayersInView:(UIView *)layerViewToAdd
{
    layerViewToAdd.alpha = 0.0f;

    [presentationDisplay setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [presentationDisplay addSubview:layerViewToAdd];


    UIView *layerViewToRemove;


    if(layerViewTag != 0)
    {
        layerViewToRemove = [presentationDisplay viewWithTag:layerViewTag];
        [presentationDisplay sendSubviewToBack:layerViewToRemove];
        // Swap the number used for the TAG (will toggle between 1 and -1)
        layerViewTag = layerViewTag * -1;
        layerViewToAdd.tag = layerViewTag;
    }
    else
    {
        // Fist time setup
        layerViewTag = 1;
        layerViewToAdd.tag = layerViewTag;
    }

    layerViewToRemove.alpha = 0.0;
    layerViewToAdd.alpha = 1.0f;
    presentationDisplay.alpha = 1.0;

    [layerViewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    [self stopSpinner];
}
```

Comment: Did you try turning Autolayout off just to see what happens?

Comment: @hw731 Just tried it and it still does not work.  Also a load of my other animations don't work either.  I am wondering if I am able to alloc a UIImageView as I am doing in the loop and add as subview!

Comment: Are you sure that `for` loop is being iterated through? I would set a breakpoint inside of it and see if it's getting looped through like you're expecting.

Comment: I put an NSLOG in there and it does at least 10 loops...

Comment: @hw731 When I add the subviews I am creating them with the same frame size as the main UIView, should I be setting up a constraint instead?  I feel the constraints are not being generated (which is why they work when app is minimised and reinstated)!

Comment: UIViews should only be accessed or manipulated from the main thread. It isn't clear from your question what you are doing or why you are using a background thread at all. Did you have a measurable performance problem doing things on the main thread?

Comment: @jrturton In short yes, it is hard to explain. A view is onscreen with lots of layers. User interacts and new view is built in the background (downloads the lot) and when it is finished the old view is removed and the new view added. This is why the built in sent in the background and the view added on the main.

Comment: Actually I have custom progress bar that updates using the same method.  Strangely when I take out the Dispatch the UIView now appears but my progress does not work (all gets executed at the end of the loop).  Is there some problem adding multiple UI updates to the same main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out after days...

So layerNames and layerImages are both NSMutableArrays, however, early in the code I had managed to comment out the Alloc Init for them.

The net result was, working fine in iOS6 and strange outcomes in iOS7.  Added this part back and it worked fine first time.

So angry with myself......... Bit worried that it managed to work at all though!